# TPL Task deadlock when calling async from sync without await in MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asynchronous, task, deadlock

I understand there's a TPL deadlock trap when calling async method within a sync MVC method, while using .Wait() or .Result to wait till the task complete.

But we just found a strange behaviour in our MVC application: The sync action calls an async method, but since it's a trigger, we never waited it complete. Still, the async method seems stucked.

Code is like below, this strange issue not 100% happens. It just happens sometime.

When it happens:

1. The HomeController.Index() action completed
2. Log.Info("Begin") executed.
3. SaveToDb() did the job, but unknown if it hanging after complete.
4. PublishTomessageQueue() doesn't do the job, unknown if it never started or just stuck inside.
5. Neither Log.Info("Finish")/Log.Error("Error") been invoked.

Most of time, code works as expected.

The ISomeInterface.Trigger() also been called from other places, windows services rather than the mvc, but this odd behaviour never happens.

So my question is, would it be possible that async tasks get into deadlock even **WITHOUT .Wait() nor .Result**?

Many thanks.

```
public interface ISomeInterface
{
    Task Trigger();
}

public class SomeClass
{
    public async Task Trigger()
    {
        Log.Info("Begin");

        try
        {
            await SaveToDb();

            await PublishToMessageQueue();

            Log.Info("Finish");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Log.Error("Error");
        }
    }
}

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public ISomeInterface Some { get; set; }

    public ActionResult Index()
    {

        Some.Trigger(); //<----- The thread is not blocked here.

        return View();
    }


}
```

Comment: I'm not very well versed in MVC, but I seem to remember that it is possible to make controller methods `async`, eg: `public async Task<ActionResult> Index()`. Then you should be able to `await` on the `Trigger` method.

Comment: @easuter Yes, you're right. And that's what I did.  The reason I asked this question is that I'm curious how could a deadlock happen in this situation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the async method seems stucked... It just happens sometime... Most of time, code works as expected.

Yes. There's a couple of major problems with this code.

First, it can attempt to resume on a request context that no longer exists. For example, the request for `Index` comes in, and ASP.NET creates a new request context for that thread. It then invokes `Index` within that request context, and `Index` calls `Some.Trigger`, and when `Trigger` hits its first `await`, it [captures that context by default](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) and returns an incomplete task to `Index`. `Index` then returns, notifying ASP.NET that the request is complete; ASP.NET sends the response and then **tears down that request context**. Later on, `Trigger` is ready to resume after its `await`, and attempts to resume on that request context... but it no longer exists (the request has already completed). Pandemonium ensues.

The second major problem is that this is ["fire and forget", which is a **really bad idea** on ASP.NET](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html). It's a bad idea because ASP.NET is designed entirely around a request/response system; it has very limited facilities for working with code that does not exist as part of a request. When there are no active requests, ASP.NET can (and will) periodically recycle your app domain and worker process (this is *required* to keep things clean). It has absolutely no idea that your `Trigger` code is running because the request that called it has already completed - thus, your running code can just disappear periodically.

The easiest solution is to move this "trigger" code into an actual request. E.g., `Index` can `await` the task returned by `Trigger`. Or have your page code issue an AJAX call to an API that calls `Trigger` (and `await`s it).

If this isn't doable, then I'd recommend a proper distributed system: have `Index` place a "trigger request" into a reliable queue and have it processed by an independent backend (e.g., Win32 service). Or you could use an off-the-shelf solution like [Hangfire](https://www.hangfire.io/).

Comment: First issue make sense. Probably I can try reproduce it.  Second one isn't an issue in my case, my app never recycles. The trigger is triggering an async task which handled by backend service cluster. It may be an practice issue, but it was not the reason cause this "deadlock" or "never returns". I had made it async action.  Just try to understand how the "deadlock" happened in the first place.  Thanks

Comment: Tested and the "First major problem" you point out is correct! The issue can be 100% reproduced if I set a task delay right after the write db method.  Thanks for your answer.

Comment: Fire-and-forget is still an issue, unless you're no longer doing fire-and-forget. The fact that your code didn't complete *and this was a problem* indicates that fire-and-forget is incorrect - fire-and-forget on ASP.NET is only appropriate for code where *you don't actually care if it runs or not*, e.g., updating a cache. If you turn off recycling (which is possible), that causes other long-term stability problems.

Comment: The recycling is turned off actually (most of recycling trigger apart from high memory usage) which seems ok so far after 3 years. Main reason it's off is there is a backend monitoring process running in the Asp.NET.  Although it's harmless if this process stop or restart, it would be much more efficient if keep it running. Reason why it's a fire-and-forget is because it's just sending a message and I don't care about the result.   But anyway, now problem sorted, like you suggested, I awaited the task complete before response. They're anyway just trigger and consume no time/resource.

Answer (score 1):

> would it be possible that async tasks get into deadlock even WITHOUT .Wait() nor .Result?

Yes, it is possible. By default the execution will be marshaled back to the original thread after the await. But if the thread is not available or blocked for some reason a deadlock may occur.

It is not sure that this is the problem also in your case but you can try the following:

```
await SaveToDb().ConfigureAwait(false);

await PublishToMessageQueue().ConfigureAwait(false);
```

`ConfigureAwait(false)` tells the runner state machine that the execution can be continued on any thread. In most cases this is alright. The marshaling back to the original thread is required only in special cases (eg. WinForms or WPF UI thread).

Comment: The inner method of SaveToDb has "ConfigureAwait(false)" called already.  The SaveToDb() method simply returns the inner method's Task output.

What I don't understand is "... will be marshaled back to the original thread after await...":  Isn't the "original thread" the one running Trigger() method?  And because the Trigger() method is async, when it "waiting" at the "await", shouldn't its' thread back to the threading pool?  Thanks.

Comment: Yes, I meant the thread, which is running the `Trigger` method as the "original" one. The awaited method _may_ run on another thread, and if there is no `ConfigureAwait`, the execution of the rest of `Trigger` will be switched back to the same thread as the first part. If this is also a pool thread it can happen that another task is executed on this thread, so the execution will be blocked until it is free again. This is a possible deadlock situation. With `ConfigureAwait(false)` the second part may continue on any thread.

Comment: Thanks for your answer taffer. So it could deadlock, but this deadlock wasn't relate to "async called by sync", right? Probably this deadlock has nothing to do with the way how I called it.